# Easiest way to find the water table under my feet

Tags: geophysics, water, underground-water

I had burnt my finger by digging an empty well and spending my hard-earned money in vain. I then started to study about the resistivity method for finding underground details. But I have many doubts arised now.

What is the resistivity of ground water in ohm-m.
How to find the exact depth at which the water is starting.
Is there any good tutorial to learn more of geophysics.
Is there any good open source software to map the underground water and tutorial for it.

Edit:
Thanks for the response, iam from southern part of India. My city is called as Chennai. We have Wells nearby.

Comment: Usually, your best bet is to get information on depth to water and yield from other wells in the area. If there aren't any other wells in the region, then that can be a sign that you may have a hard time finding a good groundwater source. The government may have watertable maps that show the elevation of groundwater in the area and reports on the typical yield. You can also look at the geology to see if it is likely that there is an aquifer at a shallow depth. Don't forget that the depth to water is usually greater at higher elevations. Geophysical methods can be tricky. Good luck!

Comment: Your question is very broad, because you are not telling us anything about the location. Please [edit] it and describe location, geography, surrounding infrastructure, etc.

Comment: you need a geological map to see where water can penetrate the ground and a topological map to see how deep down the water might be,if there is a lake/stream nearby the water level will be the same where you dig the well.